# Does the GPU process invisible things?

Tags: performance, unity-game-engine, gpu

I'm making a game in Unity 5, it's minecraft-like. For the world rendering I don't know if I should destroy cubes that I don't see or make them invisible. 
My idea was to destroy them, but creating them each time they become visible would take too much processor power so I'm searching alternatives, is making them invisible a viable solution?
I'll be loading a ton of cubes at the same time, for those unfamiliar with minecraft, [here](http://tinyurl.com/kbvxfkd) is a screenshot so that you get the idea.
That is just a part of what is rendered at the same time in a tipical session.

Comment: Minecraft does not render faces that are obscured by other blocks - you can sometimes see this when the world doesn't render a chunk correctly (you can see the holes inside the chunk such as caves and lava lakes but the rest is invisible). You need to make sure your faces which are obscured aren't rendered otherwise you will spend a lot of time rendering for no reason. Unity will probably perform backface culling, which means the faces that are facing away from the camera won't be rendered, but it probably won't understand how to cull the geometry when you are using many cubes.

Comment: I'm also not sure how much control you get over the renderer in Unity - you may need to write a plugin (I haven't used it so I wouldn't know)

Comment: Thanks @Charleh for the answer, I alredy knew what you said and that's exactly my question, which method should I use to avoid rendering the blocks that the player doesn't see, if I should destroy them or make them invisible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unity, like all graphics engines, can cause the GPU to process geometry that would not be visible on screen. The processes that try to limit this are culling and depth testing:

- **Frustum culling** - prevents objects fully outside of the cameras viewing area (frustum) to be rendered. The [viewing frustum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viewing_frustum) is defined by the near and far clipping planes and the four planes connecting near and far on each side. This is always on in Unity and is defined by your [cameras settings](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Camera.html). Excluded objects *will not be sent to the GPU*.
- **Occlusion culling** - prevents objects that are within the cameras view frustum but completely occluded by other objects from being rendered. This is not on by default. For information on how to enable and configure see [occlusion culling](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/OcclusionCulling.html) in the Unity manual. Occluded objects *will not be sent to the GPU*.
- **Back face culling** - prevents polygons with normals facing away from the camera from being rendered. This occurs at the shader level so the *geometry IS processed by the GPU*. Most shaders do cull back faces. See the `Cull` setting in the [Unity shader docs](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SL-CullAndDepth.html).
- **Z-culling/depth testing** - prevents polygons that won't be seen, due to being further away from the camera than opaque geometry that has already been rendered this frame, from being rendered. Only fully opaque (no transparency) polygons can cause this. Depth testing is also done in the shader and therefore *geometry IS processed by the GPU*. This process can be controlled by the `ZWrite` and `ZTest` settings described in the [Unity shader docs](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SL-CullAndDepth.html).

On a related note, if you are using so many geometrically identical blocks make sure you are using a prefab. This allows Unity to reuse the same set of triangles rather than having 2 x 6 x thousands in your scene, thereby reducing GPU memory load.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but it doesn't answer my question. It does help though so thank you very much and thanks for the tip.

Comment: Well if you use occlusion culling that pretty much solves the rendering load of hidden cubes. Using prefabs solves the memory usage by reusing the same polygons for each cube (I assume you have a set of materials you reuse on the different coloured blocks). Maybe I don't understand your requirements well enough... what other concerns or objectives do you have?

Comment: Also if you want to try your own approach, or supplement the builtin occlusion culling, you can spatially subdivide your world into quadtrees (2d grid) or octrees (3d grid) and place each of the leaf nodes (containing all environment cubes) in a single parent GameObject in the hierarchy. Then run your own calculations periodically to determine which tree nodes are hidden (occluded or behind the camera view) and deactivate the parent GameObject... then they won't try to render and scripts won't run.

Comment: What you answered does solve my problem and I'm very grateful to you for that. Nonetheless it does not answer the question that I specifically asked, which is "Does the GPU process invisible things?"
This is just a reply to solve your inquiries about why I didn't mark you as the correct answer. I'd still vote you up if I had enough reputation :C

Comment: I don't think Unity's occlusion culling will be useful here as it needs to be baked with a scene, so wont cover programatically placed objects (a la minecraft)

Answer (score -1):

A middle ground in between rendering the object as invisible or destroying it is to keep the C++ object but detach it from the scene graph.

This will give you all the rendering speed benefits of destroying it, but when it comes time to put it back you won't need to pay for recreation, just reattach it at the right place in the graph.